# Iterating through argument list using for loop in shell script?

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, parameters, cat

I want to display the contents of the files supplied to my shell script via arguments. I need to do this using the normal 'for (())' loop and NOT the 'for x in arr' loop.

This is my code. How should i put the file name correctly for that cat command?

```
for (( i=1;$i<=$#;i=$i+2 ))
do
    cat '$'$i   #display the contents of the file currently being traversed
done
```

Comment: In what way is "for (())" normal?  It is far more common to use the other form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
for (( i=1;$i<=$#;i=$i+1 ))
do
    cat ${!i}  #display the contents of the file currently being traversed
done
```

The corresponding manual section:

> If the first character of parameter is an exclamation point, a level
>   of variable indirection is introduced.  Bash uses the value of the
>   variable formed from the rest of parameter as the name of the
>   variable; this variable is then expanded and that value is used in the
>   rest of the substitution, rather than the value of parameter itself. 
>   This is known as indirect expansion.  The exceptions to this are the
>   expansions of ${!prefix*} and ${!name[@]} described below.  The
>   exclamation point must immediately follow the left brace in order to
>   introduce indirection.

Answer (score 2):

The normal behavior of a for loop is to iterate over the arguments.  To iterate over all arguments:

```
#!/bin/sh -e
for x; do cat $x; done
```

You can modify that slightly to only operate on every other argument as you do in your example in many different ways.  One possibility is:

```
for x; do expr $(( i++ )) % 2 > /dev/null || cat "$x"; done
```

If you insist on using the non-standard form, you can use the ${!var} bashism which will fail in the great majority of shells, or you can use `eval`

```
for (( i = 1; i <= $#; i += 2 ))
do
    eval cat '"$'$i\"
done
```